# Portable Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

I'm working on a tool in WPF to make a "sudo rcon" for a game (remote console). I've got everything finished and now I want to attach an API to it so people can create their own tools to go alongside it if they wish. I don't know anything about Aspnet but I'm sure trying to make an effort. Anyhow, this is what I have at the moment.

```
    public delegate void delReceiveWebRequest(HttpListenerContext Context);
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }

    public class HomeController
    {
        [HttpGet("/api/command/")]
        public string Get() => "Hello World";
    }
    internal class WebAPI
    {
        private static IHost _host;
        public static void Start()
        {
            _host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
               .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webHostBuilder =>
               {
                   webHostBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                   webHostBuilder.UseUrls($"http://{IPAddress.Any}:20002/");
               })
               .Build();

            _host.Start();
        }

        public static void Stop()
        {
            _host.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

The idea is to have a simple API to handle http requests **not just locally**.
Hosting it under localhost listens to requests as expected, however, running it with IPAddress.Any refuses **every** connection. It returns "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

I've seen other posts to enter net commands to make sure your IP is listening properly as well as running it in a reverse proxy, ports are also forwarded. I'm wanting to make this as portable as possible with the least amount of setup from the user (Like port forwarding, but I know that's unavoidable.)

Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: Try "http://*:20002". I don’t know if that works with UseUrls. I use KestrelServerOptions.ListenAnyIP which when first used pops up the Windows Firewall asking the user if he wants to allow external access.

Comment: That's the same thing as IPAddress.Any (returns 0.0.0.0) I don't know what happened but I guess it's working.. it's like its fixed itself, never seen that before.